# Sending tokens from Ethereum ERC 20 smart contract

Tags: ethereum, contract

As the title suggests - is it possible to send tokens from an ERC20 smart contract address, or is this unit not accessible?

Practical explanation:
A noob misunderstands some instructions and sends some tokens instead to his address to a smart contract address erc20. Is it possible for the programmers of the tokens, to recover those tokens, or are their hands "tied" and none has access to those tokens anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Both contract accounts and external accounts (controlled by humans) have all the same inherent powers. Each can do what the other can.

If you send some ERC-20 token to a contract, it can in theory send it elsewhere, providing it has that functionality already built into-it.